# Import data from CSV with custom taxomony empty

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I tried to import a CSV file (with [this](https://ro.wordpress.org/plugins/really-simple-csv-importer/) plugin ) ,and I have few empty rows at custom taxonomy (that custom taxonomy is named 'categorii', and the custom post type is name 'catalog') .What I want is when I add the CSV file and after I import it to add to the empty custom taxonomy from CSV an default one (the name is 'diverse' id is 101),I searched on internet but zero luck or I made the changes wrong .Can someone show a function example how to add default custom taxonomy to a custom post type ?

And an other problem beside this one I find that that plugin import CSV only if the data fields is divided with comma and i find [this](https://gist.github.com/hissy/d2041481a72510b7f394) but when I added to function.php and then import an CSV saved without comma didn't work,and I don't know why.